# passing same data to sibling components in angular-archwizard

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am trying to pass the value of `mobNum` of the `detailsForm` between sibling components in angular-archwizard. I tried sending the data to the parent first and then calling it inside the sibling using `@Input()` but all the components of the wizard are loaded at the same time. Below are the files for your rference:

**Parent.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="serviceName">{{'labels.auth_notice_order_heading' | translate}}</div>
  <aw-wizard [navBarLayout]="'large-filled-symbols'">
    <aw-wizard-step class="marginTheHeading" stepTitle="{{'labels.auth_notice_step_title_one' | translate}}" #wizard [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '1' }">
      <app-authenticate-notice-home (formPayLoad)="stepOneCompleted($event)" (startOtp)="otpStart.initOtp(startOtp)"></app-authenticate-notice-home>
    </aw-wizard-step>

    <aw-wizard-step class="marginTheHeading" stepTitle="{{'labels.auth_notice_step_title_two' | translate}}" #wizard [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '2' }">
      <app-authenticate-notice-otp #otpStart [otpFromServer]='otpFromServer' [payload]='payload' (moveBackToStepOne)="goToPerviousStep($event)"
        (payloadFromOtpComponent)="getPayloadFromOtp($event)"></app-authenticate-notice-otp>
    </aw-wizard-step>

    <aw-wizard-step class="marginTheHeading" stepTitle="{{'labels.auth_notice_step_title_three' | translate}}" #wizard [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '3' }">
      <app-authenticate-notice-verify #verify [responseFromServer]="responseFromServer" [messageToVerify]="messageToVerify"
        (moveToStart)="moveToStart($event)"></app-authenticate-notice-verify>
    </aw-wizard-step>
  </aw-wizard>
</div>
```

**Parent.ts**

```
 stepOneCompleted(event: FormGroup) {
    if (event) {
      this.payload = event.value;
      this.goForward();
      this.initializeObject(this.payload);
      this.getServerResponse('validateOTP');
    }
  }

getServerResponse(serviceUrl: string) {
    this.authService.getResponse(serviceUrl, this.requestObj).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Otp from server: ", data);
      this.otpFromServer = data;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

**child1.ts**

```
 validateForm(){
    Object.keys(this.detailsForm.controls).forEach(key =>{
      this.detailsForm.get(key).markAsTouched();
    })

    if(this.detailsForm.valid){
      this.formPayLoad.emit(this.detailsForm);
      this.startOtp.emit(this.detailsForm.controls.mobNum.value);
    }
  }
```

**child2.ts**

```
initOtp(mobNum){
    window.scroll(0, 0);
    console.log("mobNum at initOtp: ", mobNum);
    this.maskMobileNo(mobNum);
    this.countExpire = this.global.otpExpiryMinutes;
    this.otpAttemptsRemaining = this.global.otpAttempts;

    this.mobileOtpMand=false;
    this.invalidMobileOtp=false;
    this.otpResent=false;

    this.setMobileVal('');

    this.Mobileconfig.isPasswordInput = true;
    this.Mobileconfig.disableAutoFocus =false;

    this.visibilityMobileIconOtp = false;

    this.onMobileConfigChange();
    this.initializeTimer()
  }

maskMobileNo(mobNum){
    console.log("mobNum", mobNum)
    console.log("Payload inside maskMobileNumber function", this.payload);
    let num = mobNum;
    if(num){
      this.userPhoneNumber = " "+num.substring(0, 2) + "******" + num.substring(8)+" ";
      return true;
    }
  }
```

**Explanation:** Since all the components of the wizard are loaded at the same time, when i try `this.payload['mobNum']` in `maskMobileNo()` it throws the error `cannot read property 'mobNum' of undefined`. However, when i pass the mobile number as a parameter, it still consoles `undefined`(). How do i pass the value of mobNum to `child2` component?

**Note:** calling of `initOtp()` is done through the template variable(`#otp.initOtp()`). `child2` must be rendered before the completion of service call from parent which is why i have not used async/await or promises.

Comment: `ngOnInit` is called once after component creation, subsequent changes to `@Input` values are still registered, however, and if you want to act on them use the `OnChanges` interface.

Comment: Another option would be to add a Service that holds the data. If you do not want it to be available everywhere, you could provide it only in parent component, in that case the parent and child components will all have the same instance.